# Can't make my WCF extension work

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection

I have a WCF solution that consists of the following class libraries:

1. Exercise.Services: Contains the implementation classes for the services.
2. Exercise.ServiceProxy: Contains the classes that are instantiated in the client.
3. Exercise.HttpHost: Contains the services (*.svc files).

I'm calling the service from a console application and the "first version" works really well so I took the next step which is to create a custom ServiceHostFactory, ServiceHost, and InstanceProvider so I can use constructor injection in my services as it is explained in [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/wcf/Composing-WCF-applications.aspx).

These classes are implemented in yet another class library:
4. Exercise.StructureMapWcfExtension

Now even though I've modified my service this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Factory="Exercise.StructureMapWcfExtension.StructureMapServiceHostFactory" Service="Exercise.Services.PurchaseOrderService" %>
```

I always get the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException   Security negotiation failed
>   because the remote party did not send back a reply in a timely manner.
>   This may be because the underlying transport connection was aborted.

It fails in this line of code:

```
    public class PurchaseOrderProxy : ClientBase<IPurchaseOrderService>, IPurchaseOrderService
    {
        public PurchaseOrderResponse CreatePurchaseOrder(PurchaseOrderRequest purchaseOrderRequest)
        {
            return base.Channel.CreatePurchaseOrder(purchaseOrderRequest); //Fails here
        }
}
```

But that is not all, I added a trace to the web.config file and this is the error that appears in the log file:

> System.InvalidOperationException The service type provided could not
>   be loaded as a service because it does not have a default
>   (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default
>   constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host.

So this means that my ServiceHostFactory is never being hit, I even set a breakpoint in both its constructor and its method and they never get hit.

I've added a reference of the StructureMapWcfExtension library to all the other ones (even the console client), one by one to no avail.

I also tried to use the  option in the host's web.config file to configure the factory like so:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
    <add service="Exercise.Services.PurchaseOrderService" relativeAddress="PurchaseOrderService.svc" factory="Exercise.StructureMapWcfExtension.StructureMapServiceHostFactory"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

That didn't work either.

Please I need help in getting this to work so I can incorporate it to our project.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**: Here's the service host factory's code:

```
namespace Exercise.StructureMapWcfExtension
{
    public class StructureMapServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        private readonly Container Container;

        public StructureMapServiceHostFactory()
        {
            Container = new Container();

            new ContainerConfigurer().Configure(Container);
        }

        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            return new StructureMapServiceHost(Container, serviceType, baseAddresses);
        }
    }


    public class ContainerConfigurer
    {
        public void Configure(Container container)
        {
            container.Configure(r => r.For<IPurchaseOrderFacade>().Use<PurchaseOrderFacade>());
        }        
    }


   public class StructureMapServiceHost : ServiceHost
   {
       public StructureMapServiceHost(Container container, Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
        : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
       {
           if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

           var contracts = ImplementedContracts.Values;

           foreach (var c in contracts)
           {
               var instanceProvider = new StructureMapInstanceProvider(container, serviceType);

               c.Behaviors.Add(instanceProvider);
           }
       }
   }


   public class StructureMapInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider, IContractBehavior
   {
       private readonly Container Container;
       private readonly Type ServiceType;

       public StructureMapInstanceProvider(Container container, Type serviceType)
       {
           if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
           if (serviceType == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceType");

           Container = container;
           ServiceType = serviceType;
       }

       public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext)
       {
           return GetInstance(instanceContext, null);
       }

       public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
       {
           return Container.GetInstance(ServiceType);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Copy the StructureMapServiceHostFactory code into the question. There might be a clue in that code.

Comment: The never-ending WCF extension...How about the StructureMapServiceHost code please.

Comment: @Simon: Done. I also added the InstanceProvider just in case.

Comment: Try using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  Is the client actually making any network traffic, and does it look right?  Also, have you tried looking into the client's configuration and making sure it all is correct for what you're trying to do?

Comment: This isn't really helpful, but I had issues trying to use StructureMap with WCF. I threw in the towel early on because I found it much easier with Autofac. http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration - StructureMap needs a serious documentation overhaul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code for StructureMapInstanceProvider, it looks like it is missing the setting of the dispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider. I copied the Listing 5 from your linked web page. It is part of the IContractBehavior interface.

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
{
dispatchRuntime.InstanceProvider = this;
}
```

Comment: OMG! I just hate when that happens. I spent two hours trying to figure out why this wasn't working. Thank you so very much.